# Move files after ClickOnce deploy

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I've a simple question.
In my project (a classic WinForm, VB, .Net 4) there is a folder (named DLL), which contains some DLLs.
I've marked those file as "Content" so, during deploy, they're copied into the output folder.
In fact, after publishing the project with ClickOnce, i see them into the "DLL" folder.
Well, my question is:
How can I deploy them in the main folder (not in the DDL folder), keeping them in the DDL folder inside the visual studio project?

Comment: Although a strange construct; you could set the references to "Do Not Copy" and provide a post build step to copy the dll's to the root output directory.

Comment: I tried to do that, but the files are copied only inside the bin directory, but not in the ClickOnce output directory.

Comment: I guess click once deployment tool 'reads' the project file. In that case... you're up bantha poodoo's creek.

Comment: Furthermore I can't reference these dlls because they're not a "valid assembly or COM component".

Comment: you could build a custom structure and run mage.exe yourself from a command line (post build steps)

Answer (score 0):

try adding them as a link to the root folder while keeping them in DLL folder (Project -> Add Existing Item -> choose your file and select "Add as Link" from the bottom button):

[image]

I'm not sure if MAGE will properly pick this up - but it's worth to give a try. Don't forget to mark these files as a "Content".